# Convert active support timezone object in string back to object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

How can I convert the active support time object converted to string back to object, In other words, how can I find the active support object from its string?

Example:

```
 a = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.first = 
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007f8c45bc1848 @name="American Samoa", 
@tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Pacific/Pago_Pago>, @utc_offset=nil>
```

If I convert this object to a string using to_s, I get "(GMT-11:00) American Samoa" .

How can i find the object if i have "(GMT-11:00) American Samoa".

Answer (score 2):

This will eliminate everything between the first pair of parentheses and grab the remaining string:

```
a = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.first.to_s.match(/\(.*?\) (.*)/)[1]
```

...and with that you can find the `ActiveSupport::Timezone` object:

`ActiveSupport::Timezone[a]`

Answer (score 1):

```
# let
timezone_string = '(GMT-11:00) American Samoa'

# let's capture the "American Samoa" substring from above (as an example)
matches = timezone_string.match /\(GMT.*?\) (.*)/
timezone_name = matches[1]

# then we look up the corresponding Timezone object using the "American Samoa" timezone_name
timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[timezone_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers i did try them and it works. 
I also tried this

```
tz_value = business_timezone.split(')').second.strip
```

which gives me the name and i am finding the object using

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[tz_value].
```

Comment: Ohh no. Don't do that. Because there is a timezone that has a string like this "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"; see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html). This means that the `tz_value` will not be correct. My answer is actually following the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), in which I looked at the source code of `to_s()` to get the accurate timezone from a string.

Comment: Oh Thanks! I will go through it and modify my code accordingly :)

Comment: No problem!! :)